# Network adapter setup for Hyper-V causes continuous "Network change detected" for host PC

Tags: networking

I have setup a server in Hyper-V on my work PC. This server needs to be accessed remotely and that is working fine. To set this up I created a new Virtual Switch for this Server as the default switch didn't work. Now my work PC will regularly give me the error message "Network change detected" in chrome when browsing to a site, and it will take a while to connect to other PC's in remote desktop or via applications like FileMaker. If I disable this network in the control panel (The vEthernet adapter) then the host PC doesn't have the network change issue but ofcourse the server in Hyper-V is then no longer connected to the Internet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the default switch as the true default. Do not change it.

Then make a New External Switch and use that. You need the External Switch for remote access.

I have use the external switch setup successfully.

Comment: 1 million upvotes. That was quick and easy, now everything works fast and the server has remote access. Details, I set the server to use the default switch, Went to the virtual switch manager in hyper-v and deleted the virtual switch "LanAccess" then added a new external switch, then set the server to use the new external switch. There was a very brief loss of internet to the server and host PC but now it's better than ever.